# Ambiguity of notation: $\sin(x)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, notation

Several people have told me that $\sin(x)^2 = \sin(x^2)$. However, on several computing platforms, such as the TI-84 and Wolfram|Alpha, $\sin(x)^2 = \sin^2(x)$. Can I safely conclude that the notation $\sin(x)^2$ is ambiguous and should always be avoided in favor of $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin^2 x$? I am having trouble finding any reference through Google or in textbooks (which, I presume, avoid notation like this).

Comment: whoever told you that $\sin(x)^2=\sin(x^2)$ is just wrong.  $\sin(x)^2=\sin^2(x)=[\sin(x)]^2$.

Comment: It's likely that whoever told this to the asker meant $\sin x^2$, which can indeed be ambiguous.

Comment: @FengyangWang No, I'm definitely asking about $\sin(x)^2$. All other forms, in my opinion, are not ambiguous, although some people will (justifiably) disagree. For instance, $\sin x^2 = \sin(x^2)$.

Comment: @JoelBosveld I don't think so. I am asking about $\sin(x)^2$, _specifically_. They are asking about $\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Both $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin^2x$ are _more ambiguous_ than $\sin(x)^2$. It is just because the function $x\mapsto\sin(\sin x)$ is hardly ever of any use that those first two forms are tolerated in practice.

Comment: [I've always avoided writing “ $\sin(x)^2$ ”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058720/21813) because I tend to *first-parse* it as $\sin(x^2)$ before settling on $[\sin(x)]^2$ as per the common interpretation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No-one in their right mind would denote $\sin\left(x^2\right)$ as $\sin(x)^2$.

Why? Because the (round) brackets would become redundant.  Brackets are used to remove ambiguity in algebraic operations. If you exclude the exponent $\quad ^2 \quad $ from the brackets, you're implicitly saying that the $\quad ^2 \quad$ belongs outside the brackets, and, therefore, we're taking the square of the sine, rather than the sine of the square.

In short, $$\sin(x)^2 \ \equiv[\sin(x)]^2 \ \equiv \ \sin^2(x) \ \neq \ \sin\left(x^2\right) \quad.$$

---

In some contexts, however, for a given function $f$, we have $$f^2(x) \ \equiv \ f\left[f(x)\right] \ \equiv \ f \circ f(x) \ \neq \ [f(x)]^2 \quad ,$$ so, if in doubt, **explicitly define** notation to remove all ambiguity.

Comment: Your first line holds if it is only about a single variable. However, if `x` is defined as `y+z` you could see  `sin(y+z)^2` meaning `sin((y+z)^2)`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Agreed.

Comment: Just worth pointing out that many people have thought the $sin^2$ notation (meaning the square of the sine) senseless for a long time, for example Charles Babbage[0]. I cannot understand how any right thinking person would use it, but many still do.

[0] http://books.google.ie/books?id=gkWunaISTsgC&lpg=PA171&ots=fC_q8JHZBU&dq=babbage%20sin&pg=PA171#v=onepage&q=babbage%20sin&f=false

Comment: As David has pointed out in the comments in the below answer, $\sin[\sin(x)]$ is less common than $[\sin(x)]^2.$

Answer (score 7):

If anything, $\sin^2(x)$ is the ambiguous notation. To some it might mean $\sin(\sin(x))$ (this is why $\sin^{-1}$ is sometimes used as arcsine), and to others it might mean $(\sin(x))^2$. I cannot think of a case where anyone would see $\sin(x)^2=\sin(x^2)$ (except when, say, $x=0$). However, we mathematicians avoid ambiguity; I typically use $(\sin(x))^2$ when I square my sines.

Comment: I've always disliked how, unless I'm misunderstanding, sin^-1 represents a different function for inverse sine and sin^2 is just squaring the result of the function. It's always seemed a bit inconsistent.

Comment: $\sin(\sin x)$ is extremely rare, whereas $(\sin x)^2$ is pretty common. As such, it makes much more sense for $\sin^2 x$ to mean the latter, even though it is, as you say, inconsistent with $\sin^{-1} x$.

Comment: in my country $sin^{−1}x$ is never seen outside pocket calculators. To mention the inverse function of sin one would always use arcsin

Comment: Honestly, when I use $\sin^{-1}$, I'm not talking about a function; I use that to denote the preimage.

Comment: +1, I guess that *this* ambiguity might even be the one that was actually meant here (since, as others have pointed out, the other one does not make any sense at all). I'd go for $sin^{2}(x) = sin(sin(x))$ in any case.

Answer (score -4):

In mathematics, $\sin (x)^2 = \sin x^2 = \sin (x^2) $ because $\sin$ comes after exponentiation and multiplication in order of operations. The $sin^2$ construct was created to alleviate the pain of performing exponentiation on the result of $sin$.

In computer programming, however, $ \sin(x)^2 = \sin^2 x $ because $\sin$ is a function call and the expression within the parentheses is its only parameter.

Consider, for example, how redundant it would look to write $\sin (x+1)^2$ as $\sin [(x+1)^2]$.

Comment: What do you mean by "In computer programming, $\sin(x)^2=\sin^2 x$? Expressions such as "$\sin(x)^2$" do not appear in any programming language I'm familiar with. Squaring is typically not a primitive operation but is implemented either by explicitly multiplying a term by itself or by using a function such as `pow(x,y)` that computes $x^y$. There's no ambiguity in `pow(sin(x),2)`, `sin(x)*sin(x)` or `t=sin(x); ans=t*t`.

Comment: It's always dangerous to talk about programming languages as if they were all the same. In Python, `sin(x) ** 2` is $(\sin x)^2$ since brackets are part of the function application notation. But in Haskell, `sin (x) ^ 2` is $(\sin x)^2$ for a different reason (function application precedes all binary operations). Then, in J, `sin (x) ^ 2` is $\sin(x^2)$ due to right-associativity.

Also, esoteric languages like Unlambda will always be exceptions.

Comment: What is your justification and/or authority that "sin comes after exponentiation and multiplication in order of operations?" Is there some convention I am unaware of? Among whom?

Comment: The first paragraph is utterly incorrect.  (-1)