# Does $\sin(2x)^2 = \sin(2x^2)$ or $(\sin(2x))^2$

Tags: notation

In the notation $\sin(x)^2 $

Does this equal $\sin(x^2) $ or $(\sin(x))^2 $ ?

I'm sorry this is such a simple question but Google is unhelpful.
There are plenty of sources illustrating $\sin^2(x) $ = $(\sin(x))^2 $ but nothing about $\sin(x)^2 $

### Edit

According to the answers in my math book(*Calculus of a Single Variable 10e*, Ron Larson & Bruce Edwards), it seems as if it equates $\sin(x)^2$ as $\sin(x^2)$ This obviously isn't proof of the notation but it would make some sense when considering $\sin(x+y)^2$ or $\sin(2x)^2$ as opposed to a single variable. I find this notation very confusing and better stated explicitly such as: $\sin((x+y)^2)$ or $\sin((2x)^2)$.

I'm still not happy with this answer and would appreciate if anyone could reference evidence to one side or the other.

Comment: It can mean either, depending on the author. This is precisely why the notation $\sin^2x$ exists.

Comment: That is, there is no universally accepted "order of operations" that decides priority between function composition and exponentiation.

Comment: How can it mean either? This is important because I'm doing differentiation problems with the chain rule and this significantly changes the answer. Which is more commonly accepted among mathematicians?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I would agree there is no universally accepted order of operations, but I suspect most mathematicians would  read $\sin(x)^2=(\sin(x))^2$ but $\sin x^2 = \sin(x^2)$.  Given that most of them read $\sin^2 x = (\sin(x))^2$ but $\sin^{-1} x \not = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, their opinions can be expected to be hopelessly inconsistent.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can post the question. It can mean either because this is a bad notation.

Comment: It is ambiguous, but it "looks" like $(\sin{x})^2$ to me. Or at least I would assume it was until proven otherwise: $\sin^2{x}$ is many times more common than $\sin{(x^2)}$.

Comment: I agree this is a bad notation but this is the notation it uses in my math book.

Comment: As others said, if i saw this in the text ill read this as $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: I like the top answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932903/ambiguity-of-notation-sinx2?rq=1

Comment: How about  $sin(2x)^2=sin(4x^2)$....

Comment: I think the first comment on the first answer illustrates what I was thinking. Adding variables in the parentheses could possibly justify using that notation if you were just trying to make it shorter even though it is still confusing.

Comment: According to the answers to some of the questions in my book, it seems as if $\sin(x)^2$ = $\sin(x^2)$ in my book. I think this is for the reason Emmad Kareem comes up with.

Comment: I would never write $\sin(x)^2$, precisely because of the annoying ambiguity.  $(\sin x)^2$ and $\sin(x^2)$ are clear, and it has become universal to write $\sin^2 x$ for the former, even though it makes sense that that notation ought to mean $\sin\sin x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Where (book? pages? context?) did you find the notation $\sin(x)^2$?

Comment: _Calculus of a Single Variable 10e, Ron Larson & Bruce Edwards_, section 2.4 Exercises(pg.136) it has examples such as **47.** $y = \sin(πx)^2$, **48.** $y = \cos(1-2x)^2$, and **60.** $y = 3x - 5\cos(πx)^2)$. There are numerous other examples on this page and the answers at the back of the book correspond with using $\sin(x)^2$ or $\sin(ax)^2$ as $\sin(x^2)$ and $\sin((ax)^2)$. The instructions for these questions is to find the derivative(using the chain rule).

Comment: I [totally agree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172760/21813) with @MichaelHardy.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin^2(x)=(\sin x)^2=\sin (x)^2\neq \sin(x^2)$$